# How to get roles along with user-profiles in strapi.io

Tags: strapi

How to get roles along with user-profiles in strapi.io (to get list of all users along with roles)

Comment: Hi. It would be helpful to see the code for getting user-profiles you do now.

Comment: Hello! Your question is not clear for me, can you please precise.